# getting from query the maximum expiration and the amount of Id using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which called "`users`" which contain these columns of

`id,first_name,last_name,phone,gender,user_type`

i have another table which called "`entrance_logs`" which contain 3 colunms

```
Id. and user id,expiration
```

I have another table which called :"`gifts`" which 2 columns

```
ID and user ID.
```

I am tring to create a query which will give me the Maximum of the expiration from   the "entrance logs" column and the amount of id from table gifts.

I tried this query and it is not return to me the amount of the table of ID correctly.

```
SELECT users.first_name,users.last_name,users.phone,users.gender,users.user_type,
count(users.id), MAX(gifts.expiration),MAX(entrance_logs.datetime)
FROM  users,gifts,entrance_logs
where
users.id= gifts.user_id
and entrance_logs.user_id=users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I know I have an issue with my query I just want to know what is the problem with my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the question description, `count(gifts.id)` should be used.

Try this:

```
SELECT users.first_name,users.last_name,users.phone,users.gender,users.user_type,
count(gifts.id), MAX(gifts.expiration),MAX(entrance_logs.datetime)
FROM  users,gifts,entrance_logs
where
users.id= gifts.user_id
and entrance_logs.user_id=users.id
GROUP BY users.id
```